# cannot get all elements of array using Axios get in Javascript (Loop through an array in JavaScript)

Tags: vue.js, for-loop, async-await, axios

/*
My task is to get the user's daily work activity information from the API on this localhost page. If the user is involved in several projects, it is necessary to get more than one line of information instead of just one. My current code is code that can only get the information of the first project from the API. In this case, only one line of information can be displayed as shown in the attached photo below. I want to display more than one line of information. Maybe because the list "`time_cards`" looks like "`time_cards [0]`", I can only get the first element. I'm guessing, "Loop through an array in JavaScript" I think this method works, but I don't know how to fix the code.
Please help me guys.*/

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.6/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <v-container class="container-padding">
    <v-breadcrumbs class="px-0 pt-0" large>
      <span class="breadcrumb-line rounded-pill mr-2"></span>
      <v-breadcrumbs-item class="text-h5 mr-5">Timecard</v-breadcrumbs-item>
      <span class="breadcrumb-divider rounded-pill mr-5"></span>
      <v-breadcrumbs-item class="text-h6">View</v-breadcrumbs-item>
    </v-breadcrumbs>

    <v-card>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="3">
            <v-subheader>Insert your search date</v-subheader>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="3">
            <v-layout row wrap justify-space-around>
            <v-flex xs4 md3>
                <v-text-field v-model="calendarVal" label="Date" type="date" value="2022-02-05"></v-text-field>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs4 md3>
                <v-btn @click="fetchWorkerTimeCard">enter</v-btn>
            </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
      <v-data-table v-if="worker_time_card.length > 0" :headers="headers" :items="worker_time_card"></v-data-table>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      worker_time_card: [],
      calendarVal: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      headers: [
        { text: 'Start Time', value: 'start_time' },
        { text: 'end_time', value: 'end_time' },
        { text: 'rest_time', value: 'rest_time' },
        { text: 'worked_time', value: 'worked_time' },
        { text: 'duration', value: 'duration' },
        { text: 'work_log', value: 'work_log' },
        { text: 'project_id', value: 'project_id' },

      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    calendarDisp() {
      return this.calendarVal
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    //  this.fetchWorkerTimeCard()
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      console.log(this.calendarVal)
    },
    compare(a, b) {    //hamgiin suuliin uduriig ni deer ni
      if (a.timesheet_date < b.timesheet_date) {
        return -1
      }
      if (a.timesheet_date > b.timesheet_date) {
        return 1
      }
      return 0
    },
    async fetchWorkerTimeCard() {
      if (this.calendarVal == null) {
        // get today
      } else {
        try {
          await this.$axios.$get('/worker_time_card', { params: { work_date: this.calendarVal } }).then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            this.worker_time_card.push( {
              start_time: data.start_time,
              end_time: data.end_time,
              rest_time: data.rest_time,
              worked_time: data.worked_time,
              duration: data.time_cards[0].duration,  //worklogoo nemeh , axios - thenn ,try catch,
              work_log: data.time_cards[0].work_log,  //worklogoo nemeh , axios - thenn ,try catch,  axios iin doc sain unsh, tutorial uz
              project_id: data.time_cards[0].project_id,  //worklogoo nemeh , axios - thenn ,try catch,  axios iin doc sain unsh, tutorial uz
            })
          })
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
          this.worker_time_card = []
        }
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

[front end local host page image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT7vq.png)com/YxSjG.png

Comment: You need to do a loop through data for arrays, but you need return data as an array of time_cards.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you are returning an object. But not an array of objects. So you have to pass in

```
Object_values()
```

in the api call. So something like this:

```
async fetchWorkerTimeCard() {
  if (this.calendarVal == null) {
    // get today
  } else {
    try {
      await this.$axios.$get('/worker_time_card', { params: { work_date: this.calendarVal } }).then(Object_values(data) => {
        this.worker_time_card.push( {
          start_time: data.start_time,
          end_time: data.end_time,
          rest_time: data.rest_time,
          worked_time: data.worked_time,
          duration: data.time_cards[0].duration,  
          work_log: data.time_cards[0].work_log, 
          project_id: data.time_cards[0].project_id,  

        })
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      this.worker_time_card = []
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: I edited this and published the whole code. I am using the UI framework Vuetify for this project. I'm guessing if I should create two objects in the "worker_time_card: []" nested list inside the "data ()" function.